# Placing a PHP variable in a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having issues placing a PHP variable in MySQL string,

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("***","***","***","***");

function getItem($itemNo)
{
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$itemNo'");

    echo $itemNo;
    echo "<br>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['product_id'] . " " . $row['product_name'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
getItem(1001);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

The page shows my echo of the `$itemNo`, but thats all. If I just do `select * from products`, it gives my entire table like it should, so I know the database is working, 
so I've narrowed it down to the placement of the variable.

**EDIT**:

`product_id` column is an **int** and also the **primary key**.

Comment: what is the type of product_id ? if the type is int or bigint then just use $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = $itemNo");

Comment: its an int, i gave that a go, and it didnt work.

Comment: are you doing anything like - you have data like 001001 in db and passing in the function only 1001 ?

Comment: Is that your actual database login in your supplied code? Surely that's something you should be keeping to yourself?

Comment: As Jimmy mentioned, you've left your login data. An edit was done to remove it, but people can always see the history. It would be advisable to change both login and password on your end.

Comment: how stupid of me, i worked out the issue, my $con were out of scope for when i was calling the function.

and changing the '$itemNo' to $itemNo allowed it to work in the query as it was just an int also.

Comment: Just a sidenote, which you probably already know. Dont do this `"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$itemNo'"` unless you are making software just for yourself. One can SQL-inject to that code pretty much anything they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = " .$itemNo );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try a prepared statement to make using variables in your queries easier.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param($itemNo);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```